# Using jquery plugin for pagination is not saving the previous page selected values

Tags: visualforce, jquery, plugin-bug

Visualforce Page:

Plugin:

```
<apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
<apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
```

Script:

```
<!----Plugin Function for paging------------->
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('table.a-table').dataTable();
    });
    </script>
```

Page:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!accountList}" var="a" columnswidth="50px,50px"
                cellpadding="4" border="1"  id="acctable" styleClass="a-table">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected}"
                                onsubmit="checkAll(this)" rerender="Selected_PBS" id="name" />
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:facet>
```

Selected Accounts Section:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Selected Accounts" id="Selected_PBS">
   <apex:dataTable value="{!SelectedAccounts}" var="s"
                    columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1"  >
                    <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!s.Name}" />
                    <apex:column headervalue="Customer Number"
                        value="{!s.AJI_Customer_Number__c}" />
                    <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!s.Phone}" />
```

Suggestions needed..

Apex class:

```
  **********Retrieve Accounts**************/
    public List<accountwrapper> getAccounts()
    {

    System.debug('Accountlistvalues...'+accountList);
       // if(accountList!= null) {
                accountList= new List<accountwrapper>();
                string s1;
                    if(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('alpha') == 'All')
                       s1='%';
                    else

                       s1= apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('alpha')+'%';
                       system.debug('alphabet ordering'+s1);

         for(Account acc: [Select a.Name, a.Phone, a.ParentId, a.Ownership,a.BillingStreet,a.BillingCity,a.BillingState,a.BillingCountry,a.shippingStreet,a.ShippingCity,a.ShippingState,a.ShippingPostalCode,a.ShippingCountry,a.AJI_Customer_Number__c,a.OwnerId, a.AccountNumber,a.lastmodifieddate, (Select Id From Contacts), (Select Id From Opportunities)  From Account a where a.Name like :s1  order by a.Name,a.lastmodifieddate desc ]) {
         System.debug('Account>>>>>>>>>>>>'+acc+acc.contacts.size());
         accountList.add(new accountwrapper(acc,acc.opportunities.size(),acc.contacts.size()));
                                                        }
                               //   }

    return accountList;

    }

    /*************Selected Accounts*******************/

    public PageReference getSelected() 
    {
    selectedAccounts=new list<Account>();
    System.debug('Selected account list'+accountList);
            for(accountwrapper accwrapper : accountList) 
                { 
                    if(accwrapper.selected==true) 
                            { 
                    se1.add(accwrapper.acc); 
                    system.debug('setttt'+se1); 

                            }

               else    {
                    se1.remove(accwrapper.acc);

                            }

                 } 

             selectedAccounts.addall(se1);
            return null;
    }

/****************Retrieve Checked Accounts******/
public list<Account> GetSelectedAccounts()
{
    if(selectedAccounts.size()>0)
      // getSelected();
return selectedAccounts;
else
return null;

}    


/****************Wrapper Class*****************/

public class accountwrapper
{
        public Account acc{get; set;}
        public Integer OppCount{get; set;}
        public Integer ConCount{get; set;}
      public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public accountwrapper(Account a, Integer oppcnt, Integer concnt)
        {

            acc = a;
            OppCount = oppcnt;
            ConCount = concnt;
           this.selected = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: The way you are using jquery datatable plugin is not correct. If you want the feature of checkbox selection then you need to use extension called https://datatables.net/extensions/select/ . Once you use this extension, your selected values remain selected even if you move across pages and once the user wants to save the selected items, you can make a call to controller using actionFunction. I recently implemented jquery datatable in my project and it works fine. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @javanoob,This is the one used for extension,now.Is this enough?                            <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear given the limited code you have posted, but I suspect that you are not saving the selected items from the page in your controller (or in your client) as you leave page and referencing that data when you page backwards and forwards.

Your Apex `GetSelected` method (could be better named) needs to add the selected Id values for the selected rows in the current page in a `Set<Id>` field that is part of the view state and whenever rows are queried from the database use that set to determine if the boolean in the wrapper (presuming you have one of those) that represents the checkbox should be checked or not.

Alternatively you could perform the same logic in JavaScript, but that is more awkward to get right.

Comment: @Keith.This is my current code.Am I proceeding currectly?

Comment: @Pri You are not setting the `selected` field of `accountwrapper` to anything other than false so no.